# Ansible 2.13 issue with lists in host_vars

Tags: ansible

Trying to automate some per-host configuration, which requires a list of items (databases to be created per database host in this case).

The inventory file is at `./inventory/hosts`:

```ini
[dbservers]
intweb
```

Which has no `group_vars` associated, and the following `host_vars` located at `./inventory/host_vars/intweb.yml`:

```yaml
---
testvalue: test
anothertestvalue:
  - value1
  - value2
  - value3
yetanothervalue: test
```

When running the following task in a play:

```yaml
[...other lines...]

- name: Test list variables
  debug:
    msg: "List item is {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ anothertestvalue }}"

- name: Test list variable as string
  debug:
    msg: "{{ anothertestvalue }}"

- name: Test simple variables
  debug:
    msg: "{{ testvalue }}"
```

When running the playbook via

```
> ansible-playbook plays/default.yml --limit dbservers --start-at-task="Test list variables"
```

the relevant output is the following (which seems to ignore the list completely):

```
[...]

TASK [mariadb : Test list variables] ****************************************************

TASK [mariadb : Test list variable as string] *******************************************
ok: [intweb] => {
    "msg": []
}

TASK [mariadb : Test simple variables] **************************************************
ok: [intweb] => {
    "msg": "test"
}
```

What is the correct syntax to have a list such as the above defind in `host_vars`?

Answer (score 1):

Given the tree

```
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── inventory
│   ├── hosts
│   └── host_vars
│       └── intweb.yml
└── plays
    └── default.yml
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat plays/default.yml 
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Test list variables
      debug:
        msg: "List item is {{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ anothertestvalue }}"

    - name: Test list variable as string
      debug:
        msg: "{{ anothertestvalue }}"

    - name: Test simple variables
      debug:
        msg: "{{ testvalue }}"
```

works as expected when the **path to the inventory** is added to the command line

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook plays/default.yml -i inventory/hosts --limit dbservers --start-at-task="Test list variables"

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [Test list variables] *******************************************************************
ok: [intweb] => (item=value1) => 
  msg: List item is value1
ok: [intweb] => (item=value2) => 
  msg: List item is value2
ok: [intweb] => (item=value3) => 
  msg: List item is value3

TASK [Test list variable as string] **********************************************************
ok: [intweb] => 
  msg:
  - value1
  - value2
  - value3

TASK [Test simple variables] *****************************************************************
ok: [intweb] => 
  msg: test

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
intweb: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```